# Download a by ByteArray as pdf /handle error in React

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I have an api called from react. it returns a pdf file. When i click the link as href, i can download the pdf.
Now, instead of an href, i am calling a function , on clicking and from that function, i call the api. But i am not able to download the file.
This is what i am doing:

```
 fetch(<url>, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/pdf",
            "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
        },

    }).then(response => response.blob())
        .then(response => {
            var blob=response
            var reader = new window.FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            reader.onloadend = function() {
            var base64data = reader.result;
            window.open(base64data);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

I am not able to download any file. The api (written in kotlin) returns a bytearray. 
Also, if the api throws an exception instead of returning bytearray, i need to show a pop up , 
Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Function to download the file from byte array in REACT  --> 
 Jhttps://stackoverflow.com/a/73421462/8621764

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download the file you could use the [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) npm package and use it as following:

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

const file = new Blob([blob]);

saveAs(file, 'fileName');
```

To open the file in your browser:

```
const file = new Blob([blob], {
  type: 'application/pdf',
});

const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

window.open(fileURL);
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with a download instruction.

Comment: one more question, if i right click on my link (which used to be href, but now, it points to a function,which downloads pdf) , how can i get a download pdf option ?

Comment: Add a parameter to conditionally download it in the callback, else open it in your browser? As in (pseudo-code) `const doSomething = (download) => fetch(....download ? saveFile : window.open...)`

Comment: if (response != undefined){
                const file = new Blob([response], {
                    type: 'application/pdf',
                });
                saveAs(file, 'fileName');  - i have this now, how do i confiugure a right click check ? confused :(

Comment: Function to download the file from byte array in REACT  --> 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/73421462/8621764

Answer (score 1):

You can create an invisible anchor tag somewhere in your component and use it. In my solution i created an invisible anchor tag with id `invisible-link`

```
async function download(payload) {
    const response = await axios({
        url: getFileLink(payload), responseType: 'blob'
      })
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      // handle error
      return
    }
    const anchor = document.getElementById('invisible-link')
    const objectUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.data)
    anchor.href = objectUrl;
    anchor.download = getDownloadFilename(response.headers)
    anchor.click()
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl)
}

function getDownloadFilename(headers = {}) {
  const { 'content-disposition' : disposition = '' } = headers
  const keyValue = disposition.split(';').find(e => e.includes('filename')) || ''
  const [,filename] = keyValue.split('=')
  return filename
}
```

here's a [link](https://github.com/jasper95/jobhunt/blob/master/src/redux/app/saga.js#L45-#L63) of my code using this approach

Comment: nice thank you - for anyone that doesn't happen to have an element by id called 'invisible-link' you can replace that line with document.createElement('a')

Answer (score 0):

```
// Function to download the file from byte array in REACT JS   
 
const downloadPdfFromArrayBytes = (fileName = 'testFile.pdf', byteArrayResFromAPI) => {
          const arr = new Uint8Array(array);
          const blob = new Blob([arr]);
          if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
            // IE 10+
            navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
          } else {
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
            if (link.download !== undefined) {
              const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
              link.setAttribute('href', url);
              link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
              link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
              document.body.appendChild(link);
              link.click();
              document.body.removeChild(link);
            }
          }
        };
    
    
    // Example 
    // if you have api resp in byteArray as [10,12,30,20,34,49]
    
    const fileName = 'myfileexample.pdf';
    const apiResByteArr = [10,12,30,20,34,49];
    
    downloadPdfFromArrayBytes(fileName ,apiResByteArr);
```