# Problem dowloading a pdf file through browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, download

I have to present for an exam a portfolio which allows visitors to download some documentations about my projects as pdf files.

I tried using an  tag with a "download" attribute, unfortunately when I try to download the file by clicking on the link, the file is proposed to be recorded as .html or all files.

Whatever option I choose, after downloading the file, I'm not able to open it because it seems damaged or in the wrong format.

[image]

Here's the code I use :

[image]

My "demo" var is contained in an object Work as you can see on the screenshot :

[image]

In case it matters, my pdf file is stored here:

[image]

Thanks for you help ! =)

Comment: Please replace all images of code with a text-based [mcve].

Comment: what is `Test` component here? Is it a wrapper over Anchor element?

Comment: Use the network tab of your browser's developer tools. Look at the URL being requested for the PDF. It looks like you forgot to account for the path (although you failed to show us the `Test` components definition so maybe it is in there). You are probably getting the bootstrap HTML document for the react application instead.

Comment: @user1672994 Test is just a styled component of a simple anchor

Comment: @Quentin When I check through network developer tool I get an object of type HTML named [object Object] (strange no?). How can I change the HTML bootstrap ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

As a wild guess :

- your path is wrong (documents/pdt-test.pdf)
- your html is missing a doctype or a proper structure
- you need a doctype/pdf somewhere. Something like in here [Download a by ByteArray as pdf /handle error in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57709672/download-a-by-bytearray-as-pdf-handle-error-in-react)